# Replacing/Fixing Exterior "Trim" Around Door and Windows

Tags: doors, exterior, siding, vinyl-siding, storm-door

Searched all over google and found nothing related.

I'm replacing a storm door and i've found this lovely surprise (in picture) left behind it. I'd rather not install the new storm door onto this, and am hoping for some advice.

What is this "Trim" and what is it called?
How is it attached?
How can i take it off and replace it? (Is it under the vinyl siding?)

[image]

Thank you for your time fellas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was done with the siding, you're in for a fiasco. You might just trim it off to the siding's J-channel. But, it should be nailed-on along both edges. Unless you've got a Sheet Metal Brake or know how to duplicate its clean bends without a Brake, then I'd just leave it & tack it down behind the hinges. It's likely that it's covering rotted wood & what you don't know won't turn into a huge ordeal. Unless, you're up for doing it completely right.

Comment: Could you tell me what its called and expand on doing it right? I may be replacing the door behind it as well, which would require the exterior trim to come off regardless. Thank you already for your response.

Comment: It's called Trim Flashing & you typically buy it in rolls of aluminum. To do it right is to "possibly" remove the siding's J-channel to release any under-tucked Trim Flashing edge. Doing it right is replacing the entire door unit, its jamb & any rotted structural framing. After that, you may decide to just paint the door's new casing or finish wood trim & skip the aluminum stuff.

Comment: Would PVC trim be an appropriate material to use to finish around the door after a proper installation or if I were to just remove the aluminum?

Comment: Absolutely. PVC or Composite Decking. The Decking can just be screwed or nailed, but the PVC usually needs to be pre-drilled to avoid shattering. I haven't used PVC in about 5-years so try out a test piece, they may have finally changed the formula.

Comment: No problem. Have Fun.